# Discord.py How to get the id of a sent message with the BOT?

Tags: discord.py

How can I get the id of the message I send using the BOT? I'm using something like that:

```
await ctx.send("Test")
```

But then I don't know what to do to get the id. On the API reference there isn't written how to achieve that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
message = await ctx.send("Test")
```

To get the message you sent.
If you then want to get the [id](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=message%20id#discord.Message.id) of that message you can do the following:

```
message = await ctx.send("Test")
message_id = message.id
```